# How to use a lot of translations in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function in which I need to make 2 translations for the Russian and English versions. I have done it simply:

```
'message' => 'You have '.($i->sum * 2).' '.Lang::choice('coin|coins', ($i->sum * 2), [], 'en').' for #'.$this->id.'',
```

It works perfect, but now i make translation and has 3 translations, i need make something like this:

```
'message' => trans('notify.add_balance1') .($i->sum * 2).' trans('notify.add_balance2') trans('notify.add_balance3') '.$this->id.'',
```

But always i has errors, how i understand, I am missing a dot or a quotation mark somewhere when writing.

How can I write this correctly?

Comment: After the ` * 2).` your quotation marks are incorrect

Answer (score 0):

The string you use to define the options can contain arrays of numbers to apply each option. for example:

```
'balance' => '{0} zero|[1,2] little|[3,*] enough',
```

For best results, this will live in a file in resources/lang which you will reference in dot nation as the first parameter. e.g. Lang::choice('cost.balance')  would reference the key 'balance' in the cost.php file.

this can be called the same as you do above with `Lang::choice()`;

The full documentation for this is at https://laravel.com/docs/master/localization#pluralization